# Prepared statement: column cannot be null

Tags: php, mysql

I've been trying to figure out why I get this error in my prepared statement but I can't solve the problem. I get the error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: tipimage in C:\xampp\htdocs\Matt\addtip.php on line 68
ERROR: Could not execute query: INSERT INTO tips (tiptitle, tiptext, tiplink, tipimage) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?). Column 'tipimage' cannot be null
```

All the values in my database are set to type text, except Id.

```
....
else {
        /* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL
        server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "paul", "pass", "yourcomp");

        // Check connection
        if($mysqli === false){
            die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $mysqli->connect_error);
        }

        // Prepare an insert statement
        $sql = "INSERT INTO tips (tiptitle, tiptext, tiplink, tipimage) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

        if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $tiptitle, $tiptext, $tiplink, $tipimage);

            // Set parameters
            $tiptitle = $_REQUEST['tiptitle'];
            $tiptext = $_REQUEST['tiptext'];
            $tiplink = $_REQUEST['tiplink'];
            $tipimage = $_REQUEST['tipimage'];

            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if($stmt->execute()){
                $successmsg = "<div class='alert alert-success'>Tip Added Successfully!</div>";
            } else{
                echo "ERROR: Could not execute query: $sql. " . $mysqli->error;
            }
        } else{
            echo "ERROR: Could not prepare query: $sql. " . $mysqli->error;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a POST variable that wasn't sent with the request. This is what the [undefined index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4261133/1255289) notice is trying to tell you. You don't check to see if it exists before passing it to the database, so it ends up getting passed as null. Just give a default value of an empty string (here using the [null coalesce operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce)) and it will work fine.

```
$tipimage = $_REQUEST['tipimage'] ?? "";
```

Comment: Won't that mean it always gets entered into the database as an empty string?

Comment: No. Did you look at the documentation for the `??` operator?

Comment: Yeah. Ok got it.